# Best way to setup application with IP in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azureportal

I have deployed my application is Azure via App Service now everything is going fine until I was required to use the existing DNS to support it. Now the instruction to create DNS is simple enough and can be done easily but my boss don't want to mess around with the DNS setup like adding the verification id in the DNS. So he asked me to make it like what AWS have where we have an EC2 instance that has a public ip. Now how can we achieve such thing in Azure? I assume that the App Service is just like a standalone application that runs my site. But is there a way to make it like the EC2 Instance of AWS? Where we have our own Machine where we can SSH to it? And retrieve it's IP so that we can add that IP to our Reverse Proxy. The reason why we need an IP is because of this Reverse Proxy. We are using this to switch from one server to another if ever we decided to use a different server we just get the new server's IP and add it to our choices so that we can switch to it without downtime.

To summarize it how do we apply something like the EC2 Instance of AWS and have our own IP address? What should I need to add in Azure Portal?

Comment: You're comparing apple and oranges here.  App Service is a PaaS type of service and EC2 is IaaS.

Comment: @CSharpRocks thanks for the reply. I'm not familiar with how Azure really works that's why I'm just trying to illustrate what output we want if I were to compare it with our old implementation. Is there a way to achieve such result? Primarily we just want our App Service to have an IP that can be accessed publicly

Comment: Using App Service there is no way to get a single IP since that is a PaaS service which is shared with other App Services. The only way you can achieve this in Azure is by creating a Virtual Machine with a Public IP (preferably static). As @CSharpRocks you need to move to IaaS instead of PaaS.

Comment: @DanielBjörk that's what I was thinking. To setup a virtual machine and attach my app service to that. Are there any tutorial that I can follow?

Comment: You cant attach a App Service to a VM. An App Service is basically the engine running the site. e.g. IIS or Apache or similar but without the OS. So either you use App Service which is a PaaS and setup the Custom Domain OR you deploy a VM (which is IaaS) and install what ever engine you need to run your website on the VM.

Comment: @DanielBjörk would appreciate if you have a link to this and add it as an answer so that I can accept it as an answer thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using App Service there is no way to get a dedicated IP that is not shared since that is a PaaS service which is shared with other App Services. The only way you can achieve this in Azure is by creating a Virtual Machine with a Public IP (preferably static). As @CSharpRocks you need to move to IaaS instead of PaaS.

You cant attach a App Service to a VM. An App Service is basically the engine running the site. e.g. IIS or Apache or similar but without the OS. So either you use App Service which is a PaaS and setup the Custom Domain OR you deploy a VM (which is IaaS) and install what ever engine you need to run your website on the VM.

**Please note that you when you do a TLS binding with a Cert on your App Service you get a static IP but this IP is still shared with other clients.**

Documentation about Virtual Machines:

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/

Documentation about App Services:

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/

Documentation about App Service Inbound/Outbound IP

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-inbound-outbound-ips#get-a-static-inbound-ip

Documentation about Secure a custom DNS with TLS:

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-bindings#secure-a-custom-domain

[image: Diffrent types of services, IaaS, PaaS and SaaS]

Comment: So it mean it's either I use Azure App Service to run my application or use an Azure VM to setup my application inside that VM right?

Comment: @MadzQuestioning yes